# Brownian motion and exit time

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Say $B$ a 2-dim. BM started from $0$ and let $\tau_D$ be its exit time from a bounded domain $D$. Let also $\sigma_i^{\epsilon}$ be the exit time from the circle of center $B_{\sigma_{i-1}}$ and radius $\epsilon$. I read a claim that given $n \lt \tau_D$:

$$ E[|B_{\sigma_n^{\epsilon}}|^2] = \sum_{j =1}^n E[|B_{\sigma^{\epsilon}_j} - B_{\sigma^{\epsilon}_{j-1}}|^2]$$

And I can't figure out why this would be true. Can someone shed light on this passage?

Comment: If I'm not missing something, $N$ depends on the path of your Brownian motion and hence is a random variable. Moving it outside the expectation then doesn't seem to make sense

Comment: I adjusted the question to address your objection. I had somewhat misread the claim, but what needs to be proven is similar.

Comment: The same problem arises for writing $n < \tau_D$ since $\tau_D$ is a random variable so imposing this restriction requires $n$ to depend on the Brownian path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will ignore the restriction $n < \tau_D$ for the reason written in the comments and just show that the result holds for a BM in the whole space with no consideration of a domain $D$.

You can write $$\mathbb{E}[|B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon}|^2] = \mathbb{E}[(B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon} - B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon} + B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon})^2] = \mathbb{E}[(B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon} - B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon})^2 + |B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}|^2 + 2(B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon} - B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon})B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}].$$

First, consider $$\mathbb{E}[(B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon} - B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon})B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}].$$
By the Strong Markov property, $B_t^{(n-1)} = B_{t + \sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon} - B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}$ is a Brownian motion that is independent of $B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}$. Note that $\sigma_n^\varepsilon = \tau + \sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon$ where $\tau$ is the exit time of the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ about $0$ of $B^{(n-1)}$. Therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[(B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon} - B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon})B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}] = \mathbb{E}[B_\tau^{(n-1)} B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}] = \mathbb{E}[B_\tau^{(n-1)}]\mathbb{E}[B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}] = 0 \cdot \mathbb{E}[B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}] = 0 $$
where the third to last equality is by independence and the second to last is by symmetry of the BM $B^{(n-1)}$.

This means that
$$\mathbb{E}[|B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon}|^2] = \mathbb{E}[(B_{\sigma_n^\varepsilon} - B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon})^2] + \mathbb{E}[|B_{\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon}|^2]$$
which forms the basis for a simple proof by induction yielding the desired result.

Comment: Thank you. One question: in the second to last equality, you say $E[B_{\tau}^{n-1}] = 0$ because of symmetry. Why isn't $E[B_{{\sigma}^{\epsilon}_{n-1}}]$ also $0$?

Comment: @Karl Oh I guess it will also be $0$ but the argument would be a bit more fiddly since $\sigma_{n-1}^\varepsilon$ is the exit time of a ball with a random center which is not $0$ so proving that that expectation is $0$ by symmetry considerations (rather than just optional stopping) would be very slightly more involved than for the other term I considered.

Comment: Ok so just to be clear, the one you actually argued about will be 0 because the brownian motion will be uniformly distributed on the circle?

Comment: That's the way of seeing that I had in mind, yes

Comment: Just for the sake of seeing this argument to the end at least once, can you point me to any source where it’s written down to the end?

Comment: No, because I haven't even seen the context described in this question before reading this question. I'm not sure what is left to write down though?

Comment: I was referring only to the expectation being 0 due to symmetry. I’m not sure I could write it down carefully because I only ever saw it in three words. What is e.g. the density that integrated will give 0? 1/2pi d\theta?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. For that, let $B_t^\theta$ be $B_t$ rotated by angle $\theta$. Note that $B^\theta$ is equal in distribution to $B$ so $\mathbb{E}[B_T] = (2\pi)^{-1} \int_0^{2 \pi} \mathbb{E}[B_T^\theta] d\theta =  (2\pi)^{-1} \int_0^{\pi} \mathbb{E}[B_T^\theta + B_T^{\theta + \pi}] d\theta = 0$. In general, the distribution of the exit point of a BM from a domain on the boundary is an interesting object. The key 
word to search is the Harmonic measure. For the unit circle see e.g. Proposition 7.14 and the preceding paragraphs at http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~etheridg/pdecdt.pdf

Comment: In the above, $T$ is the exit time of the unit circle by $B$